# Get list items created by logged in user with REST api

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

How can I get all list items created or changed by the currently logged in user with [this function](http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/)? What's the correct query?

```
// Getting list items based on ODATA Query
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our colors ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [$filter](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption) query option with `Author` property to filter items by `Modified` field:

```
$filter=AuthorId eq <UserId>
```

### How to retrieve current user via SharePoint REST API

If the current user is not determined, then it could be requested using the following method:

```
function getCurrentUser(url,complete, failure)
{    
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/currentUser",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Afterwards, you could retrieve my list items as demonstrated below.

Example: retrieve my list items using SharePoint REST API

```
function getMyListItems(url, listname,complete, failure) {
  getCurrentUser(url,
    function(user){
       var query = '?$filter=AuthorId eq ' + user.Id;    
       getListItems(url,listname,query,complete,failure); 
    },
    failure
  );
}
```

### References

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: You can generally get the current user via _spPageContextInfo.userId. Saves you having to make a service call.

Comment: Thanks Rob, indeed, in most cases there is no need to make an additional request for getting current user Id.

Comment: I don't have a column 'AuthorId' but I can use 'Author/Id'

Comment: Nice. But to get user Id without any request please have look at Akhoy's answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153571/is-there-a-variable-for-current-user-in-sharepoint-2013-restful-api

Comment: @jlai79 I know this is old, but for the benefit of those coming upon this thread... The `CreatedBy` field has the underlying field name of `Author`.  But that field has 3 parts, the `Id`, `Name`, and `Email`. When using the filter to access them, you don't use slashes or dots, they just run them together in the JSON that is returned:  `AuthorId` is correct in the filter that is supplied here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is much you can do since the list only stores the User Id. Rather than querying the UserInformationList for the Id, you can grab it from **_spPageContextInfo** if you are doing this from the client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){ 
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId; 
    var restURL = url + "?$filter=AuthorId eq " + userId;

    $.ajax({        
      dataType: "json",       
      url: restURL,       
      success: function(data) {  
        //iterate through json objects and output 'my items' to a table 
      }     
    });  
  });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Display items created by user id 1

var currentUserId  = 1;

var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
        "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$orderby=OfficeLocation,Department,FirstName&$filter=AuthorId eq " + currentUserId + "&" + "@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },

            success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    alert(result[i].FirstName);
            alert(result[i].LastName);
           }
        }

        error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        }
```