# get author items REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to get the items of specific author :
this is my query :

```
http://site/sites/fr/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Activites')/items?$filter=Author eq '1'
```

the error :

> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollection.TryWriteAsOData(ServerStub serverStub, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.Write(Object value, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)

any idea

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AuthorId` or `Author/Id` instead of `Author` in `$filter`, and need no apostrophe around the value, like:

```
http://site/sites/fr/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Activites')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq 1
```

If it does not work, you can try this as well:

```
http://site/sites/fr/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Activites')/items?$filter=Author/Id eq 1
```

See [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95456/get-list-items-created-by-logged-in-user-with-rest-api) as well.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me `"?$filter=Author/Id eq '" + localStorage["idUser"] + "' &select=Author/Id $expand=Author/id ";`