# Is there a variable for current user in Sharepoint 2013 restful api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In sp2013 restful call, I have this link

```
http://mysite/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v, propertyname='Office')?@v='aq\test'
```

And this works with managed properties, but I don't want to supply the actual username for the current user. Is there some variable like `@me` or something I can use to mean the current user?

Thanks

Comment: What about: mysite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Office

Comment: Doesn't work with custom properties/ but the one I have works

Comment: Where are you using the REST call? If it's JS, you don't need to supply the username, you can use var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId; and pass that userid

Comment: do you mean accountname=@v where @v is the user id number?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. Can you show it as an example url, maybe my syntax is off.

Comment: Maybe you can use a workaround like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/get-current-login-user-profile-properties-through-rest-api/

Comment: That requires me to download the full list of properties which isn't that good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I couldn't find a way to retrieve the custom user profiles by using the user profiles REST api since the properties are returned in an array and AFAIK no existing method exists to filter them from the URL but since some of the OOB user profile properties are stored to the user information list, you can maybe try this:

```
var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
var url = "https://siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items("+userId+")?$select=Office"
```

`

Comment: I love the simplicity of a single line to get the user id _spPageContextInfo.userId

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://site/_api/web/currentuser`. This should return the current logged in user that is used to send the REST query.

Comment: This works but still requires me to make 2 ajax calls. One to get username then one to get managed property...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `user profile properties` for a `current user` via `REST API`, then you can either pass `user id` and get all `properties` including your own custom or use method `GetMyProperties`.

**Code where you pass userId.**

`userInfo.UserProfileProperties.results[10]` is a bit of code where you get available user profile properties. If I am not wrong then custom properties will be at the last indexes like `60, 61` this you need to identify.

```
function getUserInfoSuccess (data) {
    var userInfo = data.d;
    alert(userInfo.UserProfileProperties.results[10]);     
}

function getUserName() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
        userAccount = clientContext.get_web().getUserById(_spPageContextInfo.userId);

    clientContext.load(userAccount); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        var index = userAccount.get_loginName().indexOf('|') + 1,
            loginName = userAccount.get_loginName().substring(index);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='" + loginName + "'",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                getUserInfoSuccess(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed to get user. Please refresh page.");
            }
        });
    },
        function () {
            alert("Failed to get user. Please refresh page.");
        });
}
```

---

**Usage of GetMyProperties**

1) Get all properties of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

2) Get single property of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/PictureUrl
```

OR

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl
```

3) Get Multiple Properties for the current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,AccountName
```

For more details refer [SharePoint 2013: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: like I said in my first post, this doesn't work with custom managed properties...

Comment: @omega : I have updated my answer with code which I used to retrieve custom properties.

Comment: This looks like 2 ajax calls

Comment: @omega : Yes in `getUserName` first you get `useraccount` by `userid`, then with useraccount you make a call to get all the properties including `custom`

Comment: I wanted only 1 ajax call...